# Given the table R1 what is the result?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, having

```
A   B   C
3   1   0
5   2   3
5   4   2
2   6   3
```

Given the table R1 what is the result  ?

```
Select R1.A , count(*) 
from R1 (select A from R1 GROUP BY A ) R2
where R1.A >= R2.A 
group by R1.A 
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

Comment: I don't get it Soleiman. Why don't run you it to see?

Comment: Is it a quiz or something??

Comment: That query is malformed after the first `FROM R1`.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no set functions are involved? (In the subquery.) Simply do 
`SELECT DISTINCT` to get distinct values...

Comment: It will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your query is missing a comma after first R1. If you added that, You result might look like below -

```
Select R1.A , count(*) 
from R1, (select A from R1 GROUP BY A ) R2
where R1.A >= R2.A 
group by R1.A 
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

Result -

```
A  |  count(*)
--------------
3  |  2
5  |  6
```

Comment: That result is not correct. The count for 5 should be 6.